# Binding abstract events to event handlers

Tags: scala, events, types

**edit**: Looks like what I am trying to do is not possible due to the homogeneous nature of the types within collections.

---

I want to bring in `events` and `handlers` for those in a typesafe way for some kind of "state machine".

What I mean by "typesafe" is, that *instead* of having each handler doing pattern matching on an arbitrary event and only doing some magic if it's an event it is interested in, I would like to have a common place like

```
val eventsAndHandlers = Map(
    StartEvent -> new StartHandler,
    EndEvent -> new EndHandler
  )
```

to define the (currently 1:1) mapping between events and handlers. (This may well change in the future, but at the moment I am curious as to why I fail here)

What I have so far:

```
trait Event

abstract class EventHandler[E <: Event, R <: Any]
{
    def handle(event: E): R
}

case class StartEvent() extends Event
case class EntryEvent() extends Event

class StartHandler extends EventHandler[StartEvent, Unit]
{
    override def handle(event: StartEvent): Unit = println("StartHandler doing its work!")
}

class EndHandler extends EventHandler[EndEvent, Unit]
{
    override def handle(event: EndEvent): Unit = println("This is the end!")
}
```

and somewhere in the application I would have this:

```
def main(): Unit = update(StartEvent())

def update(event: Event with Product with Serializable): Unit =
{
    eventsAndHandlers(event).handle(event) // This throws a compile time error
}
```

Now, this does not compile:

> type mismatch; found : test.Event with Product with Serializable required: scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0[Product with Serializable with test.Event]

and I wonder what I am missing.

So instead of having a handler handling all the events, I want to kind of only give it the event he is interested in, based on that map. So I want to find the handler actually able to handle a given event.

edit: Just to clarify what I meant with "handling each event"

```
trait EventId

case class StartEventId() extends EventId
case class EndEventId() extends EventId

class Event(val id: EventId)

abstract class EventHandler[R <: Any]
{
  def handle(event: Event): R
}
```

in each handler then something along these lines:

```
override def handle(event: Event): Unit =
{
    event.id match
    {
        case x:EndEventId => println("The end is near!")
        case _ => println(s"Handler is not interested in that event")
    }
}
```

And to start/update the state machine:

```
def main(): Unit = update(new Event(StartEventId()))

def update(event: Event): Unit =
{
    eventHandlers.map(
        h => h.handle(event)
    )
}
```

So each eventHandler would get each event and act (or not).

Comment: which line is the error on ?

Comment: eventsAndHandlers(event).handle(event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have trouble with the map, the map only has 2 types. `Map[Key,Value]` for all Key's their value is of the same type. Your trying to tie together the subtype of the key to a value that uses the sub type. But the compiler has lost that information, it doesnt know that its the subtype. You can pick it out again with pattern matching, but thats defeats the point.

You may need to annotate your map with something like this, but I think you will still have trouble.

```
Map[Event, EventHandler[_,_]]
```

You could try putting your combinations in a list and filtering them, but I think you eventually need to have some code that executes matches and discards for each type of event. Which is what your trying to avoid.

The simplest thing I can come up with that gets around this is to have your handle method accept any `Event` and discard if its not for the handlers concrete type.

```
class EndHandler extends EventHandler[EndEvent, Unit] {
  override def handle(event: Event): Unit = {
    event match {
      case e: EndEvent => println("This is the end!")
      case other => println("unsupported event type, something wrong in map")
    }
  }
}
```

### or pattern match

The other thing you can do that is completely type save is put your combos in a big pattern match statement rather than a collection data type. Your handlers probably dont change dynamically anyway.

```
def handle(e: Event): Unit = e match {
  case e: StartEvent => StartHandler.handle(e)
  case e: EndEvent => EndHandler.handle(e)
}
```

Comment: So basically, what I am trying to do is not possible because of the homogeneous nature of the types within collections?

Comment: I think so. Well said. You could try using an HList from shapeless to keep all of the type info for your definition list.